# How to draw values lower than ... in pie chart?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have uploaded the CSV file (searches.csv is now searches) and I need to draw a PIE CHART with values bigger than 1000.
I use 2 columns from that CSV file: count and residence.
residence contains countries, they are not unique:
US
US
US
UK etc.
count- its a number.

I did an aggreagtion:

```
data1= aggregate(searches$count, 
              by=list(searches$residence), FUN=sum)
colors = c("red", "yellow", "green", "violet", "orange", "blue", "pink", 
"cyan") 
print(data1)
pie(data1$x, data1$Group.1,col=colors,main="Pie Chart of Countries")
```

My question is:
where should I put the condition for values (summed ones) lower than 1000 (sum of counts for particular country)?

Comment: `new_data <- data1[data1$count > 1000,]`...?

Comment: How to add another condition for string comparison?

     new_data <- data1[data1$count > 1000,data1$Group.2="xxx"]

?

Comment: It depends what you mean. You can have multiple conditions separated either by *or* (`|`) or *and* (`&`)

Comment: new_data1<-data1[(data1$x>200000) & (data1$Group.2=="xxx"),] 
, right?

Comment: don't forget the comma at the end (see my first comment) to filter on rows.